# Typescript (node) production / deployment best practices

Tags: node.js, typescript, deployment, production

This seems to be a dumb question, but I didn't found relevent information.

Let's say that I have this basic TS project:

```
node_modules/
src/
| app.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

When I do a basic build, this is what results:

```
dist/
| app.js
node_modules/
src/
| app.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

But then, what should I take to deploy the project?

My first approach would be to include the `package.json` inside the `dist` folder. This folder would then be my standalone "production-ready" package. On deploy, I would just do a `npm install` and then run the script.

But it does not seems to be the best practice, and it has some drawbacks (for example, I'm struggling to include a local lib [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74557921/typescript-local-library-building-with-references-and-compsite) ).

So should I include all the files in the production package? It seems strange to me to include TS sources in a compliled package.